# Grails override default email validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, grails, email-validation

I found that the grails validation rejects certain valid email addresses also. I have opened an issue on github [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9184)

Is there a way to override the default email validation in grails so that I can write my own validator for this purpose?

**EDIT**

I have solved this issue by adding the latest version of apache commons validator in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile "commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1"
```

But yet I will leave this question open as still I would like to know how do I override the default grails email validator. I want it in a way so that in domain class where I have used some constraint like this:

```
emailId(email:true,nullable:false)
```

I should not be changing this `email:true` in domain class. This should be overridden somewhere, so that the `email:true` constraint uses my logic to validate the email id.

Comment: You can take a look here http://www.zorched.net/2008/01/25/build-a-custom-validator-in-grails-with-a-plugin/. This won't override the default email validator but you can create a new one and use that instead of the default one.

Comment: @AshrafPurno I know of that. That way we can not use emailId(email:true,nullable:false) I need a way so that I don't have to change the domain class constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `email` constraint and use `matches` instead. I leave the regex up to you :)

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html

Comment: see edit. i do not want to change the domain class constraints . I just want them to behave the way I want by overriding.